# DTMC: Stationary Distribution with Recurrent Classes

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, transition-matrix

I want to calculate the stationary probability, $\pi_j$ for a DTMC that contains two irreducible classes such as,
$$
P_{ij} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
*(This should represent two irreducible recurrent classes $A\equiv\{0,3\}$ and $B\equiv\{1,4,5\}$: I just created this so let me know if I've made a typo)*

I would like to calculate the long term behaviour of P,

$$
\rho = \lim_{n\to\infty}(P^n)_{ij}
$$

Starting in $A$ or $B$, we are already in a periodic recurrent class. However, starting in $\{2\}$ we have an equal probability of transitioning to $\{0\}$ or $\{5\}$.

I am unsure how to incorporate this first step into my calculation of $\rho$

Comment: The set $B$ is not a class. The limit of $P^n$ does not exist, for example $(P^{2n})_{00}=1$ while $(P^{2n+1})_{00}=0$, for every $n$. Drawing a diagram of the state space and the transitions with positive probabilities would help you to visualize the behaviour of this Markov chain.

Comment: Ah thanks. I think I need to introduce a bias and a self recurrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=\{0,3\}$ is a closed class since $P_{03}=P_{30}=1$, and thus is also absorbing. It is also the only closed class.  Since $$P_{13}=\frac12, P_{20}=\frac12, P_{40}=\frac12, P_{53}=\frac12$$ are positive, the probability of absorption is $1$. Since $$\sum_{j\in A} P_{ij} = \sum_{j\notin A} P_{ij} = \frac12$$ for each $i\notin A$, the time until absorption $\tau$ is geometrically distributed with parameter $\frac12$, and so $\mathbb E[\tau]=2$. The stationary distribution of $\{X_n\mid X_0\in A\}$ is simply $(\pi_0,\pi_3)=\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)$.